# find permutation of an array with duplicates. Why pass by value in recursion (C++ implementation)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, duplicates, permutation

There are different ways to find all permutation of an integer array with duplicates. Here I only talk about the recursive method without using an additional "visited[]" array.

There correct way to do it is:

```
    void helper(vector<vector<int>>& ans, vector<int> nums, int pos) {
        if(pos == nums.size()-1) {
            ans.push_back(nums);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = pos; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if(i == pos || nums[i] != nums[pos]) {
                swap(nums[i], nums[pos]);
                helper(ans, nums, pos+1);
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        helper(ans, nums, 0);
        return ans;
    }
```

It is not so clear to me why it passes nums[] as a copy into the recursive function. So I looked around and on [geeks for geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-permutations-with-repetition-of-characters/) , it says that "The idea is to fix the first character at first index and recursively call for other subsequent indexes". I was thinking that I can fix the first character then recursively call for the other subsequent indexes by passing nums[] as reference and "swap back" when recursion is done (as below). But unfortunately it did not work.

```
void helper(vector<vector<int>>& ans, vector<int>& nums, int pos) {
    if(pos == nums.size()-1) {
        ans.push_back(nums);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = pos; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if(i == pos || nums[i] != nums[i-1]) {
            swap(nums[i], nums[pos]);
            helper(ans, nums, pos+1);
            swap(nums[i], nums[pos]);
        }
    }
}
vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    int n = nums.size();
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    helper(ans, nums, 0);
    return ans;
}
```

I am wondering what is wrong when passing nums[] as reference into recursion? Why passing nums[] by copy into recursion is correct?

Comment: I think I found the reason. Passing by value and passing by reference give two totally different algorithms. To understand that. Let's first note two important observations: 1. The first thing we did is to sort the array, why? because we want that all the permutations are visited in the "next permutation" order, i.e. 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.  2. The subproblem in the next recursion also maintained the sorted property.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. Passing by value and passing by reference give two totally different algorithms. To understand that. Let's first note two important observations:

1. The first thing we did is to sort the array, why? because we want that all the permutations are visited in the "next permutation" order, i.e. 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.  So that there will be no duplicates.
2. The subproblem in the next recursion also maintained the sorted property.      Let's use an example to illustrate this. 
   Input nums = [1,2,2,3] passing by value to recursion,  with pos = 0,

   i = 0: subproblem is [2,2,3],

   i = 1: subproblem is [1,2,3],

   i = 2: skipped,

   i = 3 subproblem is [1,2,2].

All the subproblems in this level of recursion are all SORTED. 
But if [1,2,2,3] is passed by reference, the subproblems are NOT sorted, so you can not reply on "next permutation" method to give you non-duplicated permutations.

If you are still confused, please take some time to read through this discussion:
https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8831/a-simple-c-solution-in-only-20-lines/28?page=2